# SAS Create Multiple tables

Tags: sas

I'm creating 7 different tables (tmp1, tmp2...tmp7) by using the code below. Every acc table has the same columns and names, the only difference is that every table is in a different library (test1, test2...test7).  Is is possible to do some sort of loop, instead of typing the code below 7 times?

```
proc sql;
    create table tmp1 as
    select * 
    from test1.acc 
    where datepart(timestamp) in
        (select max(datepart(timestamp)) 
              from test1.acc);
  quit;
```

Comment: I'm unclear to what your exact question is, how to simplify your query? And what is your issue with the time stamp?

Comment: Have you used the SAS macro language?  It is one approach for avoiding copy-and-paste.  It is a language that is used to generate SAS code instead of typing it yourself.  You might also consider just reading all seven tables into one SAS dataset.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using the SAS Macro language, which is designed for cases like this.  I won't go into a big discussion, but the following should work.  Fair warning, I did not test this, so I might have a syntax error in there somewhere, but if nothing else, this should give you a basis for finishing the solution.

/* Macros start with the %macro keyword.  Macros CAN take parameters, but there are none needed in this case.  Macro-specific commands are denoted with a '%' character. */

```
%macro read_multiple_files;
    %do i = 1 %to 7;
        /* from this point forward, the use of '&i.' will resolve to the
           appropriate loop counter 1-7 */
        proc sql;
            create table tmp&i. as
                select *
                    from test&i..acc
                        where datepart(timestamp) in
                            (select max(datepart(timestamp)) 
                                 from test&i..acc);
        run; quit;
    %end;
%mend read_multiple_files;
/* The '%mend' command doesn't really require the name of the macro to be appended, but I consider it to be good practice to include it */

/* The preceding code defines the macro program.  Now to execute the job, you NEED one last command. */

%read_multiple_files;
```

I hope this is helpful.  You will find that Macro programming is very usefulin lots of instances.  Here is a good white paper to get started.
http://www2.sas.com/proceedings/sugi29/243-29.pdf.